# Probabilities problem - exams success rate

Tags: probability

There is a an exam, containing 24 questions. Each question has 5 possible answers, and only one of them is correct, so, clearly, probability to get lucky is 0.2.

What is the probability of 50 students(OUT OF 50, ALL OF THEM) scoring at least 12/24 points? I think I have found the probability of one student PASSING the exam, but it's probably not the right way!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS7R4.png)

Comment: $50$ out of how many???

Comment: Oh. 50 - all of them. Basically all of the students passing the exam. I inserted the number just in case it matters.

Comment: Could it be that the students studied (at least to some extent) for the exam, and so (one could hope) that their results would be better than random guessing?

Answer (score 1):

For a single student, the probability is $\sum\limits_{n=12}^{24}\binom{24}{n}\cdot\left(\frac15\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac15\right)^{24-n}$

For $50$ students, simply raise the value above to the power of $50$.

Comment: Oh. What is that first sign in the equation? It stands for a row, doesn't it? It's the sum of every equation with every n from 12 to 24? 
What's the result only for when n = 12? I just want to make sure I undestand everyhing correctly. Thanks!